# Hardware logic gates for a simple demo with LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics

I need some logic gates for a simple demo like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDf2vEcyDfs). I will use a regular breadboard and an Arduino UNO as a 5 V and GND supply.

I found these ICs from Texas Instruments SN74LSxxN (NOT, AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR). For my demo I only need two inputs (well obviously only one on NOT) and one output on each chip. I want to connect the output to a LED via resistor to demonstrate that for example 1 XOR 1 equals 0 (LED off), or NOT 0 equals 1 (LED on):

[image: demo circuit]

My LSs seem to work as expected without an LED connected:

[image: works well]

```
int value;

void setup() {
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(1200);
}

void loop() {
 digitalWrite(10, LOW);  
 digitalWrite(11, LOW);
 value = digitalRead(5);
 Serial.println(value);  
}
```

…but it would be great to make an LED demo too.

These ICs are probably a better choice in my case?

- SN74ACT04N (NOT)
- SN74ACT08N (AND)
- SN74ACT32N (OR)
- SN74ACT00N (NAND)
- CD74ACT02 (NOR)
- SN74ACT86N (XOR)

For everyone who isn't happy with Arduino as power supply here an alternative circuit with the same question - which IC family should I use?

[image]

**Update:** Well, probably I should better use something like [LogicBlocks](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11006) for my demo.
There is no NOR, XOR or NAND in this set, but it should be much easier to handle.

Comment: No, that is not OK. Those chips have ±4mA outputs at 5V. You are asking around 15mA (depending on LED forward voltage).

Comment: Majenko could you recommend some suitable ones?

Comment: GeMir, you can increase the resistor, say to 2K, and see if you have enough brightness.  Some high-brightness LEDs are ok with up to about 15K series resistance at 5V.  Note, see Ohm's law.   5V/200Ω = 25 mA, too much for typical 74HC outputs to source. [Actually, the calc. should be (5V-Vled)/200]   5V/4mA = 1250Ω, so a 2KΩ is ok.  Or you could add a buffer to drive LEDs.

Comment: @jwpat 1.8 kΩ carbon ones?

Comment: GeMir, those should work ok.  The current calc. for red LEDs at say 1.6V drop would be (5-1.6)/1800 = .00188, a little less than 2 mA.  You could go as low as about 1K; (5-1.6)/1000 = .0034.  With white LEDs at say 3.4V, (5-3.4)/1000 = .0016 = 1.6 mA and (5-3.4)/470 = .0034 = 3.4 mA.  Anyhow, you don't need anything except a meter, an LED, a resistor, and a 5V supply to test if LEDs are bright enough at low enough current.

Comment: @jwpat7 Should I better change the family? The ACT family outputs are ±20mA.

Comment: You *cannot* drive only one gate on each chip. The other floating inputs could cause power issues, so tie them to one of the rails.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sure, I'll use only two inputs and all other ones will be connected to GND. Thank you.

Comment: GeMir, first run a test with a meter, an LED, a resistor, and a 5V supply to see how much LED current you actually need.  If you need more than 3 or 4 mA, you could change families or use a buffer.  For example, run a 74HCxx output through an SN74ACT245, or through 2 inverters on an SN74ACT04.  Note, if you are only making one of these demo units, the chip costs might not be a factor; if you are making several, the 74ACT parts probably will cost several times as much as 74HC parts.

Comment: A 1k resistor will let around 3 mA through an LED with a 2V forward voltage drop (from a 5V source). On a test here with a cheap LED it was quite visible when on. `(5 - 2) / 1000 = 0.003`. See [LED calculator site](http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz)

Comment: @NickGammon I found something very similar to the demo I want to make on YouTube (see the first post above).

Comment: Note: Lengthy series of posts by the OP on the same issue on [the Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=444853).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit I was looking for looks like this:

[image]

And the HC family seems to do the job. Thanks to **dlloyd** ([link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=444853.45)).

Comment: I gather you have decided to source 9.7 mA from the 74HC08N output driver. Since the device is specified to provide ±4 mA I'm just curious to know why you did that? You are running at 243% of its documented ability.

Comment: @NickGammon It was dlloyd's recommendation, I've got HC- and ACT-family chips and use ACTs now.

Answer (score 2):

The SN74HC04 has a [documented](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc04.pdf) output driver capability of ±4 mA when running at 5V:

[image: SN74HC04 datasheet]

Assuming you are using red LEDs with a forward voltage of 1.6V (as I measured one of mine lying around on the bench to be), then to not exceed this you need to get a resistor of:

```
(5 - 1.6) / 0.004 = 850 Ω
```

A reasonable (and safer) value would be a standard 1k resistor, which you are likely to have lying around (and if not, get a few hundred of them). That would give you 3.4 mA current through the output pin, which is in range.

---

> I found something very similar to my demo on YouTube ...

Yes, well, people on YouTube aren't always doing things exactly like they should. :)

See Mike Cook's tutorial [The care and feeding of LEDs](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Tutorial/LEDs.html). As he points out, a lot of people use the wrong, or no, resistors because "it seems to work".

It may well seem to work for a while, but if you want a design that will last for a long time, you work within the manufacturer's specifications.

The problem with people disseminating wrong information is that someone will then copy it, and repeat it, and before long you find people saying "everyone does it this way".

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanations! Since SN stands for "Texas Instruments" and there is no SN74ACT02N (NOR), shouldn't I look for CD74ACT04, CD74ACT08 etc. (I prefer buying parts of same manufacturer)?

Comment: Ok, found it. CD means "CMOS digital logiс IC". These chips were made by Harris Semiconductor.